# Checking Macbook Pro Retina SSD life

Tags: osx, ssd, smartctl

I am trying to assess the health of my SSD drive (of a MBPr 15" mid-2014). I tried to do `smartctl -a disk0`, which gave the following output:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 40
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED      WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3005
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2767
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   253   253   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       1885834579712
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   190   190   100    Old_age   Always       -       8609857595
174 Host_Reads_MiB          0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       5571155
175 Host_Writes_MiB         0x0022   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       6795580
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       49
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   059   059   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 16/66)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Unknown_SSD_Attribute   0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

I don't understand how I can get `190` as the `Wear_Leveling_Count`. I'm not really sure how to interpret the other numbers either. Could you help me understand what these numbers mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these macbooks use samsung SSDs (correct me if I'm wrong).
[Here is a link to a SSD white paper from samsung explaining the SMART data.](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/whitepaper/whitepaper07.html)

there it says: ID # 177 Wear Leveling Count

This attribute represents the number of media program and erase operations (the number of times a block has been erased). This value is directly related to the lifetime of the SSD. The raw value of this attribute shows the total count of P/E Cycles.

However, they do not exactly explain what the columns `VALUE` `WORST` and `THRESH` mean. I found somewhere, that these values work as follows: "The manufacturer defines a threshold number against which the “value” is compared, and if the “value” drops below that threshold, SMART reports that attribute as FAILING_NOW, and sets the overall health as FAILED."

So I'd say a wear leveling value of 190 is perfectly fine, since it is well above the threshold of 100 (I am assuming it starts at 200 just like `Raw Read Error Rate`). If your macbook is one year old now, the ssd should last approximately another 9 years if you keep the same usage patterns.

Also, none of the attributes has a date in the column `WHEN_FAILED`, so you need not be worried, everything is fine with your SSD.

I have a MacBook Pro retina (early 2013) myself, and my smart data looks pretty similar to yours:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       5352
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       10513
169 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   253   253   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       2302974898688
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0032   193   193   100    Old_age   Always       -       12899778635
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       33
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   065   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 6/60)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

The reason my Wear Leveling Count is still a little better than yours, despite the fact that my raw value is 50% higher than yours, is likely because I have a 500GB SSD which can take more writes in total than, say, a 250GB one.